# Flash LED fine but can't output and monitor using a logic anaylser on RG0

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, pic18

I am using a PIC18F6520 and have managed to write some code that flashs an LED with a deay of 500ms, below is this code.

```
// CONFIG1H
#pragma config OSC = HS         // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config OSCS = OFF       // Oscillator System Clock Switch Enable bit (Oscillator system clock switch option is disabled (main oscillator is source))

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = OFF       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOR = OFF        // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (Brown-out Reset disabled)
#pragma config BORV = 25        // Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (VBOR set to 2.5V)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = OFF        // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))
#pragma config WDTPS = 128      // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:128)

// CONFIG3L

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MUX = OFF    // CCP2 Mux bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RE7)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVR = OFF       // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will not cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage ICSP Enable bit (Low-voltage ICSP disabled)

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not code-protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF        // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-0007FFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM not code-protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not write-protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-0007FFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM not write-protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-0007FFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000

void main(void) {
    TRISCbits.RC2 = 0;
    while(1) {
        LATCbits.LATC2 ^= 1;
        __delay_ms(500);
    }
    return;
}
```

Now if I try to change the output pin to RG0 and monitor that pin with a logic analyser I can't get the output to toggle it just sits at 0, update section of code below.

```
void main(void) {
    TRISGbits.RG0 = 0;
    while(1) {
        LATGbits.LATG0 ^= 1;
        __delay_ms(500);
    }
    return;
}
```

Am I missing something about RG0 that means it cannot be used as a digital output, or is it possibly that the output pin does not have a pull-up resistor on it and needs one for the logic analyser?
Any advice on how to get this code working please?

Comment: I don't know this MCU but took a brief glance at the datasheet. Chapter 10.7 suggests that PORTG might be muxed with other peripherals. If it is possible to re-route or disable other peripherals through routing registers, I don't know. But getting mysterious routing registers correct is kind of a FAQ for getting any MCU up and running these days.

Comment: Also, internal pull-up only makes sense for input pins. That's never needed when driving the pin as an output.

Comment: I am working with a microcontroller where 2 of the GPIO pins do not have internal pull-ups. I also use them for test purposed as output pins with logic analyser and I do need external pull-ups. For the other pins with internal pull-ups I don't need that. But I have no idea about your micro

Comment: RG0 is multiplexed with the CCP3 peripheral. Make sure it is disabled when initiating your program by setting its value to zero `CCP3CON = 0;` Because periherals may override the TRIS values when they enabled.

Comment: @Kozmotronik According to the data sheet, `CCP3CON` is zero after reset. However, it is a simple check to get a little bit forward.

Comment: That's good to hear because I was looking through the datasheet and saw that setting that register maybe a good thing to try, but unfortunately it is still  not working. I did get it working by changing the port used from G0 to A0. I have not added this as an answer as it does fix it but it does not solve the actual question, it changes how I implemented it.